# better to use rebuild for solution with many projects or clean + build

Tags: build, msbuild

Now i know there have been many questions asking about what the difference is and i understand that they refer to different MSBuild targets.

But i was wondering which would be better for a solution with multiple projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rebuild cleans and bui;ds projects one by one whereas clean + build will clean the whole solution then build it all in one go.

I would use Clean + build for multiple project solutions